# How to fix the Failed to start the systemd service using puppet

Tags: linux, puppet, systemd

I have the following systemd file I am trying to execute.

```
[Unit]
Description=WSO2 Micro Integrator Dashboards
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /mnt/4.0.1/wso2mi-dashboard-4.0.1/bin/dashboard.sh start
ExecStop=/bin/sh /mnt/4.0.1/wso2mi-dashboard-4.0.1/bin/dashboard.sh stop
ExecReload=/bin/sh /mnt/4.0.1/wso2mi-dashboard-4.0.1/bin/dashboard.sh restart
PIDFile=/mnt/4.0.1/wso2mi-dashboard-4.0.1/runtime.pid
User=wso2carbon
Group=wso2
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I try to run the file using the `puppet` as below:

```
$service_name='wso2mi-dashboard'

  service { $service_name:
    enable    => true,
    ensure    => running,
    subscribe => File["binary"],
    require   => Exec['systemctl daemon-reload']
  }
```

When I see the `journalctl -xe` logs, I get the following error:

```
-- The result is failed.
Dec 13 19:28:27 v2-tfl-triapps-test-midashboard-i-094e69fc75bb91812 systemd[1]: Unit wso2mi-dashboard.service entered failed state.
Dec 13 19:28:27 v2-tfl-triapps-test-midashboard-i-094e69fc75bb91812 systemd[1]: wso2mi-dashboard.service failed.
```

Can someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like Puppet is doing what it should do, and the service just isn't working.  Do you get a different result if you try to start the service manually (`sudo systemctl start wso2mi-dashboard`)?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes i get the same error when I try to manually start using `sudo systemctl start wso2mi-dashboard`

Comment: Then the problem is not with Puppet.  It might be with the systemd unit file or with the software itself.  The unit file appears to be syntactically correct, but it's hard to judge whether the content is right for the software.